# Refresh results in Google Colaboratory as the page loads

Tags: javascript, python, google-colaboratory

[image]

I am working on google colab as it a part of my school project.

But I got stuck on a problem. So, I wanted some one to help me out.

I want that every time the page is refreshed, a new random number generated using python gets shown up in the output area (in the image it has number 1).
I am able to run a javascript code as soon as the page loads. But I don't know how to simulate a click on the run icon. So, if someone knows how to simulate click on that run button (it's actually not a button, it's a `<div>`). Please, if anyone could help me out, I will be very thankful.

Sorry for poor english.

Code:

```
from random import randint
import IPython
print(randint(1,5))
js_code = '''
document.addEventListener("load", a());
function a() {
  var s = /* The run button */
  s.cick();
}
'''
display(IPython.display.Javascript(js_code));
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, Colab requires user interaction to execute code. There's no way to automatically execute a cell when a notebook loads.

Comment: So, is it possible to call a python function from javascript

Comment: Yes. [Here's an example from the docs](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=Ytn7tY-C9U0T). But, backend communication requires an explicit user execution of the cell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way by which I would be able to call a js function as soon as window loads. I had tried window.onload but it doesn't works for me. If possible, please post the code in the answer.