# Is it possible to run a javascript code on google colab as soon as the page loads

Tags: javascript, python, google-colaboratory

Is it possible to run a javascript code when the page loads on google colab. If possible then please post the code. I had tried `window.onload`, but it is not working. Please help me.

Code:

```
import random
import IPython
from google.colab import output

display(IPython.display.Javascript('''
    window.onload = a();
    function a() {
       google.colab.kernel.invokeFunction('notebook.ran', [], {});
    }
    '''))

def rando():
  with output.redirect_to_element('#output-area'):
    a = random.randint(1, 5)
    print(a)

output.register_callback('notebook.ran', rando)
```

Comment: *(This apparently doesn't solve your problem so moving to a comment--as it is still true.)*  If you write `window.onload = a()` then you are calling the `a` function at that moment, and assigning the result of running `a` to window.onload.  If you want window onload to actually be *the function value* you would say `window.onload = a`.  Or avoid naming the function at all, and use it anonymously: `window.onload = function() { google.colab.kernel.invokeFunction('notebook.ran', [], {}); }`.

Comment: Note also: you are using ["function hoisting"](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript#toc-hoisting-functions) to assign `a` before defining it.  That is technically legal...albeit a bit confusing in this case.  But observe the nuance that this only works if you write `function a() {...}`, not if you had said `var a = function() {...}`.  It's something to be aware of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh results in Google Colaboratory as the page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918385/refresh-results-in-google-colaboratory-as-the-page-loads)

Comment: No, this isn't possible. (Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918385/refresh-results-in-google-colaboratory-as-the-page-loads.)